# From a bar chart with multiple values per ticks to a stacked bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I succeeded to generate a bar chart from a table which provides multiple values per ticks. The code is given in the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=10pt,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    legend pos=north west,
    legend style={legend columns=1},
    ylabel={Cycles},
    symbolic x coords={4096,8192,16384,32768,65536},
    bar width=6,
    ymin=0,
    xtick=data,%
    xticklabels={$4$, $8$, $16$, $32$, $64$, $128$},
    error bars/.cd,
    yminorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    nodes near coords,
    scaled y ticks=base 10:0,
    cycle list = {black!60,black!30},
]

\pgfplotstableread{
x            bench1              bench2
4096         321                 375
8192         685                 640
16384        2550                1461
32768        5198                4637
65536        10331               9617
}\datatable

\addplot+[fill, text=black]
table [x={x}, y={bench1}] {\datatable};

\addplot+[fill, text=black]
table [x={x}, y={bench2}] {\datatable};

\legend{Bench1, Bench2}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Bar chart with multiple values per ticks]

Now I want to add the values of an other experiment on top of the previous ones. Particularly, stacked bars seem perfect for that. However, I have so much trouble to add stacked values from other tables.

---

Finally, I do not think that stack bars are appropriate.

Here is what I got using classical bar charts from concatenated tables:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{external}
    \tikzexternalize
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{zero.dat}
x           bench1              bench2
4096        321                 375
8192        685                 640
16384       2550                1461
32768       5198                4637
65536       10331               9617
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{one.dat}
x           bench1              bench2
4096        467                 1534
8192        1010                3005
16384       2807                6319
32768       5763                13556
65536       15258               27957
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{two.dat}
x           bench1              bench2
4096        577                 2132
8192        1157                4211
16384       3115                8589
32768       7638                18084
65536       21573               36204
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=10pt,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    legend pos=north west,
    legend style={legend columns=1},
    ylabel={CPU cycles},
    symbolic x coords={4096,8192,16384,32768,65536},
    bar width=6,
    ymin=0,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={$4$, $8$, $16$, $32$, $64$, $128$},
    error bars/.cd,
    yminorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    %nodes near coords,
    scaled y ticks=base 10:0,
    cycle list = {black!60,black!30},
]
\pgfplotstableread{zero.dat}{\tablezero}
\pgfplotstableread{one.dat}{\tableone}
\pgfplotstableread{two.dat}{\tabletwo}

\pgfplotstablevertcat{\datatable}{\tablezero}
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\datatable}{\tableone}
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\datatable}{\tabletwo}

\addplot+[text=black]
table [x={x}, y={bench1}] {\datatable};

\addplot+[text=black]
table [x={x}, y={bench2}] {\datatable};

\legend{Bench1, Bench2}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, I would like to fill the plots with colors. Particularly, it would be perfect if each "stacked" bar can be filled with a specific color, or specific pattern. However, if I set the option "fill" for plots, each stacked bar is colored similarly.